# Graph not plotting any points

Tags: plotting, webmathematica, education

```
f [x_] := (x + ln[x] - 3)

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

How come this comes out with an empty graph? I tried this and same results:
`Plot[[x] + ln[x] - 3, {x, 0, 4}]`

I'm new to Mathematica and confused why all my graphs come oute mpty

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You have a syntax error. `ln` is not a built-in function. Change this to `Log[x]`.

Comment: One way to figure this out is to use free form input.  Start by typing `=`, and it should show an orange equal sign, then if you type "plot x + ln(x) - 3 from 0 to 5" it gives this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5hutm.png

Answer (score 3):

If your plot doesn't show anything, it's often helpful to look what your plotted function does. If you evaluate e.g. `f[1]` in your notebook, you'll see:

> -1 + ln[1]

That's because there is no build-in function called `ln`. You probably want `Log`.